# Lua convert table to string

Tags: string, lua

I cannot find the correct solution or I get an error for something that is very simple in C: how can I convert/move data from a table to string?

The C equivalent of what I am trying to do is:

```c
for (i=0; i <10; i++)
{
    string[i] = table[i]
}
```

I can convert from string to table with `:byte(i)` but I don't understand how to append a sign in string.

Comment: So you have a table like `{"x", "y", "z"}`, and you want `"xyz"`?

Answer (score 3):

To create a string from all values in a table you can use [`table.concat`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial), this will concatenate each character in a table.

```lua
local myTable = { "h", "e", "l", "l", "o" }
local combinedString = table.concat(myTable)
print(combinedString) -- Outputs hello
```

[**Run Code Demo**](http://tpcg.io/_13I24G)

Comment: Hi Skully, is small problem.
1. Table have ASCI value, and the same result I get in print- value 49(dec) will print as 49, not ASCI "1".
2. Table start's from 0, not 1 so table.contact miss first character 

I not write it also, but table in real is 16bit where first 8bit is empty. 

my code `code
    MD_BUF[0] = 48
    MD_BUF[1] = "a"
    MD_BUF[2] = 50
    MD_BUF[3] = 51
    MD_BUF[4] = 52
    MD_BUF[5] = 53
    MD_BUF[6] = 54
    MD_BUF[7] = 55
    MD_BUF[8] = 56
    MD_BUF[9] = 57

    string_buf = table.concat(MD_BUF)
    print(string_buf)
`
result: a5051525354555657

Comment: Sorry, I cannot win with text formating when at comment writing ;/

I try to use loop with MD_BUF[i] = string.char(MD_BUF[i]) before table.concat but still I error with bad argument.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you mean, is your array full of hexadecimal values that you want to convert to characters? Also, you can paste your code and update your existing question and explain what you mean there more clearly - if you can provide an input and expected output, it would be helpful to understand what you mean.

Comment: I want to send text to device and display it. Table who keep this data is 16bit but I use only ASCI. So, in my table  I have:
   `code BUF[0]= 0x48
    BUF[1]= 0x65
    BUF[2]= 0x6c
    BUF[3]= 0x6c
    BUF[4]= 0x6f`

And this table I need to change to string who give me "hello" when I print it.

Sorry, I really try to past code here, but I don't know where I made mistake with formatting